# DataTables filters column when clicking on input field inside Header

Tags: jquery, select, datatables, multi-select

I have a DataTables instance that appends a select in the header of a table. [Here](https://codepen.io/abolfazl-the-sans/pen/OJjQxON) is a codepen showing it.

Here is the relevant part of code that adds the select to the header

```
        initComplete: function () {
            count = 0;
            this.api().columns().every(function () {
                var title = this.header();
                //replace spaces with dashes
                title = $(title).html().replace(/[\W]/g, '-');
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<br><select id="' + title + '" class="select2" ></select>')
                    .appendTo($(column.header()))
                    .on('change', function () {
                        //Get the "text" property from each selected data
                        //regex escape the value and store in array
                        var data = $.map($(this).select2('data'), function (value, key) {
                            return value.text ? '^' + $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(value.text) + '$' : null;
                        });

                        //if no data selected use ""
                        if (data.length === 0) {
                            data = [""];
                        }

                        //join array into string with regex or (|)
                        var val = data.join('|');

                        //search for the option(s) selected
                        column
                            .search(val ? val : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });
                //unique, tipo group by 
                //sorte deixa em ordem abcd
                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                });

                //use column title as selector and placeholder
                $('#' + title).select2({
                    multiple: true,
                    closeOnSelect: false,
                    placeholder: "Select a " + title
                });

                //initially clear select otherwise first option is selected
                $('.select2').val(null).trigger('change');
            });
        }
```

However I noticed that one downside of putting it in the header, is that when I click into the select, DataTables thinks I am sorting by that column. Is there a way to not sort the column if I am clicking inside the select (which has ID equal to the column name)

Edit: I am looking for a solution that does not trigger the the column sort when I click on an `input` element inside the header column.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can do it.

First is to disable sorting on click altogether. Just put this in your table options:

```js
ordering: false,
```

The other option is to have two rows in the header. The first row should be `th` with your column header, the second should be your dropdown filters inside a `td` cell. This is because DataTables reserves a space inside `th` cells for the sorting arrows even when they are not there.

```html
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Demanda</th>
        <th>Título</th>
        <th>Solicitante</th>
        <th>Data Inclusao</th>
        <th>Área</th>
        <th>SP</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

You would need to change your `appendTo()` to something like this:

```js
.appendTo($(`#example thead tr:eq(1) td`).eq(this.index()))
```

Then in your table options you can set

```js
orderCellsTop: true,
```

this will allow sorting when you click the top header row and filtering from the dropdowns in the second header row.

Comment: This solution works but it's not necessarily what I'm looking for. Using a second row looks weird because only 2 of the columns have dropdowns. I would prefer to just make it so onclick inside of input doesn't sort

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I made for same problem is:

```
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
    var target = e.target;
    if ($(target).closest("th").hasClass("sorting") && $(target).prop("tagName") == "INPUT") {
        /* You can replace or add more element types in condition. */
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: This works pretty well for not triggering the sort but if you click an item in the dropdown (one of the `li` elements, it will trigger the sort. I even added a check if the `tagName` is `LI` and the `e.stopPropagation();e.preventDefault();` didn't stop the sort.

Comment: Try replacing `$(target).prop("tagName") == "INPUT"` by `$(target).closest("span.select2-container").length > 0` in your condition.

Comment: Still the same. I tested and replacing everything with your new `.closest()` code is hit (length is 1), the `e.stopPropagation();e.preventDefault();` doesn't do anything. My latest [codepen](https://codepen.io/abolfazl-the-sans/pen/OJjQxON) shows this.